# Intellij should use single brace in Typescript files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea, ide

How to ask intellij to use single brace for auto-imports ?

- **Like that** :

  ```
  import {module} from '/service';
  ```
- **Instead of** :

  ```
  import {module} from "/service";
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to editor => code style => Typescript => Punctuation tab => select "single" from Use dropdown